# visitor counter in php when open/close or leave the page

Tags: php, mysql, counter, visitor-statistic, visitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can I make visitor counter in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862686/how-can-i-make-visitor-counter-in-php)

I want to insert when page open/close or leave but not onunload .. the below code help me to insert when open the page , but not when close or leave

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["visits"]))
    $_SESSION["visits"] = 0;
if ($_SESSION["visits"] > 1){
    echo 'visit='.$_SESSION["visits"];
    echo "You hit the refresh button!";}
else{
    mysql_query(
        "INSERT INTO najd_visit( visit_userId, visit_staticId, visit_page,
            visit_enterTime)VALUES ('$userId', '$Sid', '$title', '$date') ");
    $_SESSION["visits"] = $_SESSION["visits"] + 1;
    echo 'visit='.$_SESSION["visits"];
    echo "This is my site";
}
```

Comment: This is the 3rd time you have asked this question in some form. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784163/how-unset-session-when-close-the-web-page-in-php , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862686/how-can-i-make-visitor-counter-in-php

Comment: yes , I am new of using this website ... still try how to use it

Comment: Only ask one question and make edits to it if you need to rephrase your wording. Also, please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

You cant run something via PHP when someone "leaves" the page - because the browser nevers sends anything to your server to trigger the script.

You only possible option is to use javascript and run it as they leave - but its going to be temperamental and unreliable at best.

Comment: help me with some codes in javascript to insert in mysql when I close the page

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript and Ajax.
Javascript: [Intercept page exit event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event)
Ajax - http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Edit: I don't think that you can do it without unload, php is a server-side language, not user-side.

Comment: thank you but I dont know ajax , still beginner

Comment: Go to the link that I gave you, it's very simple.